# Proxy Error - Error During SSL handshake

Tags: apache, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

We have an application that posts some xml data to another application and traffic flows through apache web server (version 2.2.26) reverse proxy.  we are observing some sporadic Proxy Error (http response code 500) - SSL handshake error with the remove server. The error message is shown in apache web server error logs.

Earlier we were using sunOne web server and we didn't notice this error. 
i am suspecting that may be some missing configuration on apache web server that is causing this issue. this is just my guess.

Please advise if anyone has any experience around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very strange issue where Apache complained about SSL Handshaking but it turned out to be something else, finally the issue got resolved by placing the **SetEnv proxy-sendchunked** in **rproxy.conf** file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Microsofts IIS, maybe it helps you.

There was a problem with the compression, the proxy did not support gzip so I forced the proxy to set the compression to none.

Afterwards (outboundrule), I changed the compression back to the original header sended from client.